# How to insert PHP script into HTML the best way?

Tags: php, html, insert

I have to insert full path to every single image/css file of my website, because of url_rewriting and I'm looking for the most officiant way to do it.

Of course I could do:

```
<img src='<?php echo $full_path; ?>/images/theImg.jpg' alt='alternative text' />
```

But somewhere I saw people doing it like this, or something:

```
<img src='{full_path}/images/theImg.jpg' />
```

Now do you know how the second example is possible, or is it just part of some framework and can't be used in normal document?

Thanks for answers,

Mike

Comment: In this very case you don't need any variable full path. `/images/theImg.jpg` is all right.

Comment: Not if you mod_rewrite the adrress for something like shop.com/product/product-name and want the img from shop.com/images/img.jpg and not shop.com/product/images/img.jpg

Comment: Just try it. `/images/theImg.jpg` works for the `shop.com/product/product-name` as well as for the every page on the site. It is called `absolute path` and the only solution for the filenames.

Comment: the first code example is absolutely fine

Btw, you can just use ../images

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Depends on the mod_rewrite rules. Relatives paths are considered relative to the *rewritten* address.

Comment: OMG @nico dont't talk of the things you understand not! ../images is relative path and leads you to the hell. And any sensibe mod_rewrite rules has nothing to do with absolute image paths.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Why does it not work for me then? or better, why does it only work if I use "shop.com/product/product-name" and not "shop.com/product/product-name/"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I am just telling what happens when I use relative paths with mod_rewrite. If it doesn't work for you maybe it is because you're using different rewrite rules. I'm absolutely positive about this because I've used it in many a situation. I can also tell you that ../ can work perfectly when used correctly.

Comment: Mike, what's in your $full_path variable?

Comment: 'http://localhost/huntingShop/'

Comment: with http://, but stackOverFlow dowsn't show it

Comment: @niko of course relative path *can* work but only a fool would use it. Because it's relative. While absolute path remains **the same**, a relative one should be adjusted for the every directory.

Comment: Mike well `/huntingShop/images/theImg.jpg` is the way to go. and mod_rewrite has nothing to do with it.

Comment: How would I do it on real server btw? if I had shopname.com ?

Comment: though it could be a problem when site moved to the production. The best solution is to set up a local domain for the  site, a (http://)shop.local/, and use it instead of localhost/huntingShop/

Comment: well, it must be www.domainname.com .. no other option :S

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: absolute paths can be better in some cases, but again IT DEPENDS ON THE SITUATION. Relative paths are absolutely useful in certain situations, even with mod-rewrite. I'm not saying they're the solution to the world's problems, just that IT DEPENDS on the design of the site. Not every site has an unknown/variable number of subdirectories for instance...

Comment: Mike it doesn't matter. when you program a site, it's code has nothing to do with site domain. You can take any script from the internet and it will run on your site with no problem, right? So, your shop will run as well. All scripts is domain-independed. You can develop on the domain.local and then deploy to www.domainname.com. However you can set up www.domainname.com on the local machine using .hosts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just part of some framework and can't be used in normal document.

Answer (score 1):

And if it's not a full framework, perhaps it's just a templating engine like Smarty http://www.smarty.net/